# SAXParseException creating an Enum in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm having trouble constructing my first XSD file. I'm trying to generate Java POJO's bases on my XSD with `jaxb2-maven-plugin`.

To start, I've followed the example that I've seen [this tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/XML/0060__XML-Schema/EnumeratingASimpleType.htm)

This is my `xsd` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <xs:element name = "Tshirt">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = "Color" type = "clothesColorType" />
                <xs:element name = "Size" type = "clothesSizeType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="clothesSizeType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="S" />
            <xs:enumeration value="M" />
            <xs:enumeration value="L" />
            <xs:enumeration value="XL" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="clothesColorType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Black" />
            <xs:enumeration value="White" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Green" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Blue" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

When my plugin try to parse the file, I get the error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/ruta/src/main/resources/wsdl-definition/Assurance.xsd; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 72; src-resolve: No se puede resolver el nombre 'clothesColorType' para un componente 'type definition'.
```

I have been googling for hours but I have not found the response. Any Ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you also show the configuration of  jaxb2-maven-plugin? And could you please check, that this schema file is the only one in folder src/main/resources/wsdl-definition ?

Answer (score 0):

The schema is valid (Saxon accepts it, so it must be...)

The problem is therefore either with your schema processor, or with the way you are invoking it.

I note that your schema does not have 47 lines, therefore I suspect the file you are actually using differs from the one shown.

Comment: The lines that are not showed are commented. It is the file that is being processed.

Comment: Well, what you have shown us is fine. The problem is with something you haven't shown us. That's all I know.